# blockUI is not working as expected

Tags: jquery, blockui, jquery-blockui

I have a following jquery code

```
$("#tbl").block({ message: 'Updating...' });
    $("#tbl > tbody > tr").each(function (i) {
    ...
    }
$("#tbl).unblock();
```

Now my problem is blockUI only works after it come out of the loop. How can I blockUI before entering the loop and unblock UI after loop?

Comment: Are you sure your `.each()` isn't simply running so fast that blockUI is starting & stopping quickly?

Comment: Well it's not I tried by taking out the unblock code and it only block when it's out of the loop.

Comment: JavaScript isn't asynchronous in the way you are expecting. The blockui code is using JavaScript to do the animation over time in a fake asynchronous way, but the update to the table is blocking the animation code from running. What you can do is wait until the blockui has finished fading in before starting the loop.

Comment: @HJ05 can you give me some example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use the `onBlock` callback available in BlockUI.

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#btn').click(function() { 
        $.blockUI({ 
            fadeIn: 1000,
            message: 'Your message here...',
            onBlock: function() {
                var x = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
                    x = (x*x)*(x*x);
                    x = x*i;
                }
                $.unblockUI();
            } 
        }); 
    });    
});
```

Here is a working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XcE3J/6/)

Comment: thanks for your help. How can I change default loading message "please wait" to different message.

Comment: You would change the default message with the `message` parameter. Updated answer and [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XcE3J/6/) to include it.